# both app:showAsAction="ifRoom" and android:showAsAction="ifRoom" do not work as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library

I have an options menu defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
      android:title="@string/action_favorite_add"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="2"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      />

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_info"
      android:title="@string/action_info"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="3"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      />
</menu>
```

The options menu itself works correctly, however the ifRoom actions do not collapse to an overflow when I have a longer toolbar title. Instead the toolbar title gets truncated.

If I use `android:showAsAction` instead of `app:showAsAction` and I ignore the error regarding the support library, the items are always collapsed to an overflow. No matter the length of the title.

I should also mention, that the toolbar is within a collapsible toolbar

I would like to the have the search action item to appear always (no matter the length of the title) and the other two items to appear only if the toolbar title is not truncated.

**UPDATE**: layout and onCreate

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/rm_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/rm_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rm_expanded_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rm_img_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:imagePlaceholder="@{@drawable/img_placeholder}"
                    app:imageUrl="@{vm.imageUrl}"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <!-- Some other layouts overlayed over the image view -->

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/rm_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@{vm.name}"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- rest of layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  activityComponent().inject(this)

  setAndBindContentView(R.layout.activity_some_activity, savedInstanceState)

  setTranslucentStatusBar()
  setSupportActionBar(binding.rmToolbar)
  supportActionBar?.let {
    it.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    it.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
  }

  binding.rmAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object: AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    override fun onStateChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?, state: State) {
      if (state != State.IDLE) { // collapsed or expanded
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
      }
    }
  })

  // some other view code

  // viewModel load code
}
```

Comment: `ifRoom` working as intended if you have space on toolbar you will see item in toolbar otherwise in overflow-menu. it will not collapse to overflow menu if toolbar collapse. you need to detect collapsing toolbar collapse event and call `invalidateOptionMenu()`.

Comment: @Abhishek Singh good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I have the title of the collapsible toolbar disabled and the title is always on top. I have also added an appbar layout offset listener and invalidated the options menu on collapse - no change.

Comment: if title of the collapsible toolbar disabled which title are you showing?

Comment: of the toolbar itself

Comment: have u used `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: yes `setSupportActionBar(binding.rmToolbar)` `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` `supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)`

Comment: can you show your layout and java code so that i can try by myself

Comment: hey are you try just using app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" in menu.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Please try this hope so it will be helpful for you. I don't know if this works in general but in my case it does:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
      android:title="@string/action_favorite_add"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="2"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
      />

  <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_info"
      android:title="@string/action_info"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
      android:orderInCategory="3"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
      />
</menu>
```

Comment: Yes! Unfortunately, this always collapses the items. Even when the title is very short and there is enough space for all 3 items. Thanks, though.